# Missing LUKS + LVM support for Odin (v6) installer

Tags: system-installation, release-odin, full-disk-encryption

I'm trying to install Elementary OS Odin into a virtual machine with LUKS + LVM partitions set up and the installer doesn't allow me to config the partitions

drive setup:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda mktable GPT
sudo parted /dev/sda mkpart fat32 2048s 512MiB # 2048s is the best alignment for my drive
sudo parted /dev/sda set 1 esp on # flaggin partition for EFI boot
sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sda1
sudo parted /dev/sda mkpart unformatted 512MiB 100%
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat --type=luks1 /dev/sda2 # grub doesn't boot luks2 drives
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 mydrive
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/mydrive bs=8M # Wait till no space left error
sudo pvcreate /dev/mapper/sda2
sudo vgcreate elementaryOS /dev/mapper/sda2
sudo lvcreate --name swap -L2G elementaryOS
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/elementaryOS-swap
sudo lvcreate --name boot -L1G elementaryOS
sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/mapper/elementaryOS-boot
sudo lvcreate --name system -l100%FREE elementaryOS
sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/mapper/elementaryOS-system
```

Then I started the installer, which asks me for the password to unencrypt (luksOpen) my drive and nothing happens after it.

[image: installer asking for encrypted disk password]
[image: installer confirming that the volume was successful unencrypted but no actions at all]

Comment: I am running into the same issue. With the old Ubiquity installer, it should show the Logical Volumes after the LUKS partition is decrypted.

Comment: @Livy, Stack exchange seems like a community knowledge share place. Sadly ElementaryOS lacks a public issue system where we can report and track the fix of issues like these

Comment: My purpose is to dual boot a Bitlocker Windows partition alongside eOS luks2 partition. I used to install Windows first, and then select the luks2 partition when installing eOS. If your purpose is the same as mine, you can use the installer to wipe the whole partition and install eOS, then manually shrink the storage stack (file system -> logical volume -> volume group -> physical volume) to make space for installing Windows. It is very troublesome and the downside is you cannot re-install eOS on the disk without wiping it.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this issue as well.

Forgive, me, I'll be documenting a lot of what I've done in order to benefit future users and also so that I have a canonical source on how I do this as I'll be installing Odin on two other systems shortly.

> ⚠️ **NOTE**: I'm terribly sorry for how long this is, there is a summary at the bottom, but I needed to provide context for everything and discuss how things *used to work* in order to discuss how things "work" now.
>
> [I have hosted this in a Gist if this is too long for an answer](https://gist.github.com/naftulikay/3398cce7e25762eb675e50b0ed5de7a6). You might also be wondering how I know all of this, and all I can say is
>
> [image]
>
> I have suffered hundreds of hours over the years to achieve this setup, and I'm too far in to question whether it's worth it, but the benefits of full-disk-encryption, BTRFS compression and subvolumes, rEFInd, etc. are worth it for me.

### History

> **⚠️ NOTE:** Most of this entire history section is no longer working, but the steps are still relevant for the actual answer at the bottom.

I have a complicated disk setup, not using LVM but using BTRFS for multiple subvolumes (with compression) so that I reduce the amount of read/write on the device and increase the amount of storage space. I won't go into that right now, but it's something I've been doing for a while and ubiquity (the previous, Ubuntu installer), *would* actually allow you to do what you're discussing above, elementary OS Odin does not. I'd also usually pass a flag to tell it to not install a bootloader, as I like to use rEFInd, which is much prettier and nicer to work with than grub.

##### Disk Setup

> Note that when I use `$LUKS_UUID`, I mean the output of `blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/nvme0np3)`; when I open the device, I give it a name `luks-$LUKS_UUID`, yielding a device path of `/dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID`; when I use `$ROOT_UUID`, I mean the internal BTRFS filesystem UUID acquired via `blkid -o UUID -s value /dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID`; I also assume EFI, so `$EFI_UUID` is the FAT32 partition's UUID for `/dev/nvme0np1`, and I assume that a second partition exists for hosting the initramfs and other boot stuff at `/dev/nvme0n1p2` (filesystem choice largely irrelevant but I use BTRFS) and I'll use `$BOOT_UUID` to reference its UUID.

The way to get it working before was:

1. Setup the dm-crypt/LUKS/cryptsetup volume at `/dev/nvme0n1p3`

   ```
   cryptsetup luksFormat --cipher aes-cbc-essiv:sha3-256 --hash sha3-256 \
       --iter-time 5000 --pbkdf argon2id ... /dev/nvme0n1p3
   ```
2. Unlock the device using:

   ```
   cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 luks-$LUKS_UUID
   ```
3. Create the inner BTRFS filesystem:

   ```
   mkfs.btrfs -L my-computer-name /dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID
   ```
4. Mount the BTRFS root:

   ```
   mount /dev/mapper/luks-$(blkid-s UUID -o value) /mnt
   ```
5. Create subvolumes:

   ```
   btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@           # mount point: /
   btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@home       # mount point: /home
   btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@var        # mount point: /var
   btrfs subvolume create /mnt/@virtualbox # mount point: /virtualbox
   ```

   Ignore the VirtualBox mount point, VirtualBox has always had problems with BTRFS, so I symlink the disk image directory to this mount point and mount with `nodatacow`.
6. Unmount:

   ```
   umount /mnt
   ```
7. Run the installer without installing a bootloader.

The old installer would allow you to do this, it would allow you to use the `/dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID` as `/` and Ubuntu used the same subvolume names as listed above so it played fairly nicely.

##### `chroot` and Configure the System

After running the installer, it then became necessary to `chroot` into the machine's filesystem, so:

```
# btrfs subvolumes
mount -o defaults,subvol=@,compress=lzo /dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID /mnt
mount -o defaults,subvol=@var,compress=lzo /dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID /mnt/var
mount -o defaults,subvol=@home,compress=lzo /dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID /mnt/home
mount -o defaults,subvol=@virtualbox,compress=lzo /dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID /mnt/virtualbox
# unencrypted boot partition containing initramfs etc.
mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/boot
# the EFI volume
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
# system mount points to ensure chroot works
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /run /mnt/run
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs /mnt/sys
```

> Bonus points: since the installer most likely did not mount with compression enabled, now would be a good time to compress the filesystem recursively, as doing it in a live system is probably not a great idea, so:
>
> ```
> btrfs filesystem defrag -r -v -clzo
> ```
>
> This compresses the filesystem using LZO, which is a good middle ground compression algorithm, not too CPU expensive, with decent compression overall.

Next: `chroot /mnt` and if you did everything correctly, you'll now be living virtually inside of your install, so you'll be able to do customization here.

##### `chroot`

```
chroot /mnt
```

⚠️ From this point on, you are now *inside* your elementary OS install. I'll let you know when to exit it.

##### Setup `/etc/fstab`

The installer never quite got `/etc/fstab` right, so install an editor and edit `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=$BOOT_UUID /boot btrfs defaults 0 2
UUID=$EFI_UUID /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1

/dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID / btrfs defaults,compress=lzo,subvol=@ 0 1
/dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID /home btrfs defaults,compress=lzo,subvol=@home 0 2
/dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID /var btrfs defaults,compress=lzo,subvol=@var 0 2
/dev/mapper/luks-$LUKS_UUID /virtualbox btrfs defaults,nodatacow,subvol=@virtualbox 0 2
```

Be sure to replace those variables with your actual UUIDs.

##### `/etc/crypttab`

I wasn't *exactly* sure how `/etc/crypttab` worked, it usually didn't seem to do anything at all for me, but I'd always set it up anyway perhaps out of paranoia:

```
luks-$LUKS_UUID /dev/nvme0n1p3 none luks
```

##### Install rEFInd (optional)

Install the rEFInd PPA if you want a nice graphical boot manager that's easy to customize:

```
apt install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:rodsmith/refind
apt update
apt install -y refind
```

##### Ensure Crypto Modules in initramfs

After doing this, the initramfs would usually *not* contain the `dm-crypt` and `cryptsetup` modules, which was super frustrating to debug, but I'd usually go and edit `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot` and force the hook to install the `cryptsetup` dependencies. The hooks have changed significantly, so this did not seem necessary in my Odin install, but on all of the previous elementary versions, I had to do this; I'd usually add an echo statement to the hook to emit a simple message indicating that it was, in fact, adding the modules to the initramfs.

Rebuild the initramfs via `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

At this point **your initramfs and your actual machine config should be able to boot.** However, we're not done, we need to update the kernel command-line to use arguments that were necessary to ensure the kernel knew that it needed to decrypt the root filesystem.

##### Updating the Kernel Command Line

> Note: I'm using rEFInd, you're probably using grub, so you'll need to look up the way to edit the grub kernel command line. I've had correspondence with Rod Smith and he's been extremely helpful in the past, can't recommend the bootloader enough, I wish it could be the default bootloader but everybody still uses grub.

To set the kernel command-line in rEFInd, you'll need to edit `/boot/refind_linux.conf`. Each line here represents a different boot option. Specifically, we'll need to set the following:

- `root`, which indicates to the kernel where the root filesystem should be found; our root filesystem is inside of a LUKS container, so if you only pass this, the kernel won't be able to find your root.
- `rootflags=subvol=@`, which tells the kernel to pass `subvol=@` when trying to mount the root filesystem; this makes sure that we're using the correct subvolume at boot time.
- `cryptopts=target=luks-$LUKS_UUID,source=UUID=$LUKS_UUID`, which tells the kernel to look for a partition with the `$LUKS_UUID` as its identifier, and to open it as `luks-$LUKS_UUID`.

Remember to replace the variables as you edit `/boot/refind_linux.conf`:

```
"Normal"   "ro root=UUID=$ROOT_UUID rootwait rootflags=subvol=@ cryptopts=target=luks-$LUKS_UUID,source=UUID=$LUKS_UUID,options=luks quiet splash vt.handoff=7"
"Recovery" "ro root=UUID=$ROOT_UUID rootwait rootflags=subvol=@ cryptopts=target=luks-$LUKS_UUID,source=UUID=$LUKS_UUID,options=luks quiet splash"
```

Great! Now we *should* be able to boot, provided we got everything right. I often screw things up so I have to enter the installer, setup the `chroot`, try to fix things, `update-initramfs -u -k all` and iterate. Try booting the recovery option to see more of what the kernel is doing if you don't get boot right away.

---

### New Sauce ✨

Okay, so, as mentioned at the start, elementary OS Odin does not use `ubiquity` anymore, and from what I've seen, you basically cannot tell elementary OS Odin to do full-disk encryption or even user home directory encryption, which was unacceptable to me, at least. I lost about 8-10 hours trying to do the above with the Odin installer, and no dice, but I do have a booting system with full-disk encryption using LUKS.

In the end, and I really hate that I had to do this, but I essentially created a [stage-3 ala Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Stage_tarball) by destroying my LUKS container and having it create an unencrypted filesystem on `/dev/nvme0n1p3`. Still within the installer:

1. `rsync` everything in `/dev/nvme0n1p3` to an external disk.
2. Create the LUKS container.
3. Unlock it.
4. Create the BTRFS partition.
5. Mount it, create the BTRFS subvolumes, unmount it.
6. Mount `/`, `/boot`, `/boot/efi`, `/var`, `/home`.
7. `rsync` from the external disk to where you mounted your root, which so far has been `/mnt`, so

   ```
   rsync -av /media/elementary/my-external-disk/elementary-odin-stage-3/ /mnt/
   ```
8. Setup the `chroot` with the system mount points, `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/run`.
9. Enter the `chroot`.
10. Setup `/etc/fstab`.
11. Setup `/etc/crypttab`.
12. Install rEFInd (optional).
13. `update-initramfs -u -k all`
14. Setup kernel command line options.
15. <s>Pray</s> <s>Hope</s> Reboot and just see what happens.

If you were able to do all of this, you *should* be able to get to boot , though I had to boot recovery a few times to fix various issues.

#### The Broken ❌

Well, Ubuntu has changed the way it does kernel command line arguments for LUKS, and uses a new shiny `systemd` configuration in the early initramfs stages to setup your LUKS container. The `cryptopts` argument seems outdated, and seems to protest using what I previously used, and so that led me down this rabbit trail:

- [`man 7 kernel-command-line`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html)

There are new options starting with `luks*` that seem to supersede the old `cryptopts` parameter. I haven't gotten these working yet, but the man page does direct us to another interesting place:

- [`man 8 systemd-cryptsetup-generator`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/systemd-cryptsetup-generator.8.html)

It *seems* that what is implied here is that the actual initramfs is configured *when it is created/updated* that `/etc/crypttab` is finally actually used to embed configuration into the initramfs, so `cryptopts` may no longer be necessary, and using the option generates warnings for me at boot time. Maybe it just works, but I am unsure and I haven't tested it out yet, but I likely will do so in VirtualBox to see what is actually necessary.

#### Debugging

To debug things, boot into recovery mode by omitting `quiet splash` from your command line and inserting `recovery`. If worse comes to worse, you can also tear apart the initramfs using `unmkinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-$(uname -r) ./`, which is what I'm doing right now.

My crypttab seems to be in the image, which is promising, but I'll only believe it when I see it actually functioning, I've *seen things* so my skepticism is pretty formidable.

---

### Summary

In short, I documented above what *used* to work as a basis for getting things working again in Odin. What I have found so far is that **there is no way in the installer to enable full-disk-encryption** and I didn't see an option for user home directory encryption either.

As a result, I essentially ran the installer, copied all of the installed filesystem files to an external hard drive via `rsync`, created my LUKS container and filesystems etc., `rsync`ed into the encrypted container, modified some essential files in a `chroot`, updated the initramfs, updated the kernel command-line, and I can at least boot now.

I'm going to try to do all of this in VirtualBox next to see if I can get a working boot without the kernel command line arguments, hoping that it just works™, but prepared for it to totally not work.